# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' when installing xformers for Stable Diffusion on Macbook M2 Max

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, stable-diffusion

I'm working on Stable Diffusion and try to install xformers to train my Lora.

My Computer is Macbook M2 Max and already installed latest python3.11 and pip 23.1.2

```
which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3
python3 -V                                                                             
Python 3.11.3

which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/pip3
pip3 -V
pip 23.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

But every time when I use below cmd:

```
pip3 install xformers
```

I'll get message as below:

```
Collecting xformers
  Using cached xformers-0.0.20.tar.gz (7.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/05/3wghcmr93436gfgb3ty5mnmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-3da38ps7/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/05/3wghcmr93436gfgb3ty5mnmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-3da38ps7/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/05/3wghcmr93436gfgb3ty5mnmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-3da38ps7/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/05/3wghcmr93436gfgb3ty5mnmm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-3da38ps7/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've installed PyTorch using command from offical website:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

And when I run test.py using below code:

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

I'll get correct result as below:

```
python3 a.py
tensor([[0.8204, 0.4140, 0.5262],
        [0.1857, 0.3604, 0.3496],
        [0.0620, 0.2303, 0.1033],
        [0.8081, 0.2826, 0.2922],
        [0.1685, 0.5701, 0.9935]])
```

It means torch has been installed correctly.

Also I can see torch using pip3 list

```
torch              2.0.1
torchaudio         2.0.2
torchvision        0.15.2
```

I also purged all pip3 cache using

```
pip cache purge
```

It doesn't work.

I also restart my computer, doesn't work either.

I saw a lot of Q&A talking about conda, I haven't installed conda so I believe it should not be a conda relative problem.

How to fix this problem? Thanks~

Comment: same issue, any solutions here?

Answer (score -1):

I install an old version

```
pip install transformers==2.5.1
```

Then i install

```
pip install transformers
```

It works for me , but no idea why